# How i make CSS Background image outside of div to the right and left?

Tags: css

I'm developing a website that has to contain a background image outside of the div set in the bootstrap to the left and right. Someone can help me? Thank you.

What i got until now

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpgky.jpg

What i want to fill

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrnkH.jpg

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: do you even see the images? it is clear what i need in the images...

Comment: @LucasSantos You currently need to put here the code of what you tried to solve your problem. Without that we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the body background to the orange color.

Set the content container to white if it doesn't default to that.

Comment: Same principle applies it would seem. `background-image` or `background`. The point being is set the outer container's background with whatever - color, image, gradient.